# Access denied WEB-INF/classes for Hibernate with GAE

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, jpa

I am running a web application on Google App Engine and I am trying to use JPA (Hibernate 4.2).
This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="ProductionPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >

    <properties>

        <!-- Connection -->

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://***:***/***" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"></property>

        <!-- Session Management -->

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

This is all working fine until it's all deployed, but whenever I am using it locally, then it gives me this error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:387)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:58)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at it.injenia.test.Test_HibernateServlet.doGet(Test_HibernateServlet.java:43)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\Riccardo\workspace\Test%20Hibernate\war\WEB-INF\classes" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:838)
at java.io.File.toURL(File.java:686)
at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.JarVisitorFactory.getJarURLFromURLEntry(JarVisitorFactory.java:87)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:353)
... 41 more
```

It seems to run into some errors due to security policy, since it gives "access denied" for accessing resource "WEB-INF/classes".

Can someone help me out? I am literally trying everything since two days but I found nothing yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Hibernate is incompatible with AppEngine. See here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

Comment: This got submitted before I was done. I also need you to verify ... this error comes on local deployment .. right? In your question, you have written 'all working fine' till it is deployed. What does that mean? When is it working correctly? Or are you only using JPA interface?

Comment: It does work when it is deployed but not when running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error using AngularJS, GAE and hibernate.  The issue was that I had spaces in my output path.  Once I changed my output to a location with no spaces in the path name, the issue went away.